# Power series solution do differential equation given recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, factorial

While solving a differential equation I ended up with this recurrence

$$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=a_{n-1}$$
With $n=1,2,3,...$

I know that $a_{3k+2}=0$ for all $k$.
When it comes to finding series for $a_{3k}$ I have a problem expressing it correctly:

$n=1$
$$(2)(3)a_3=a_0$$
$$\therefore a_3=\frac{a_0}{(2)(3)}$$
$n=4$
$$(5)(6)a_6=a_3$$
$$\therefore a_6=\frac{a_0}{(5)(6)(2)(3)}$$
So on and so on.
So we end up with :
$$a_{3k}=\frac{a_0}{(3k)(3k-1)(3k-3)(3k-4)...(3)(2)}$$
I don't know how to express that product as a closed product. I thought about rearranging it:
$$(3k*(3k-3)(3k-6)...*3)*((3k-1)(3k-4)...*2)$$
And whilst the first bracket I found easy to solve :

$$3^k*3!$$
I can't do similar "trick" with the second one. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=a_{n-1}$$
without losing generality using the following substitution:
$$
a_k=\frac{c_k}{k!}
$$
leads to:
$$(n+1)(n+2)\frac{c_{n+2}}{(n+2)!}=\frac{c_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
and remembering that 
$$(n+2)!=(n+2)(n+1)\cdot n!$$
leads to this simplification:
$$c_{n+2}=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}c_{n-1}=n\,c_{n-1}$$
now all that is left is solving 
$$
c_{n+2}=n\,c_{n-1} \iff c_{n+3}=(n+1)c_n
$$
that is solved using the $\Gamma$ function which has this fundamental property 
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$$
Again without loss of generality set:
$$
c_n=q_n \Gamma(\alpha n+ \beta)
$$
substituting this leads to
$$
q_{n+3}\Gamma(\alpha n +3\alpha +\beta)=(n+1)q_n\Gamma(\alpha n + \beta)
$$
Applying the property of $\Gamma$ to the LHS:
$$
q_{n+3}(\alpha n +3\alpha +\beta-1)\Gamma(\alpha n +3\alpha +\beta-1)=(n+1)q_n\Gamma(\alpha n + \beta)
$$
now in order to simplify the $\Gamma$ on both sides:
$$
\Gamma(\alpha n +3\alpha +\beta-1)=\Gamma(\alpha n + \beta)\iff \alpha=\frac{1}{3}
$$
let's substitute and see what comes next:
$$
q_{n+3}(\frac{n}{3} +\beta)=(n+1)q_n
$$
setting $\beta=\frac{1}{3}$ leads to:
$$
q_{n+3}=3 q_n
$$
now all the linearly independent solutions of this last recurrence are obtained using:
$$
q_n=K^n
$$
substituting gives the characteristic equation:
$$
K^3=3 \iff K_{i}=\sqrt[3]{3},\,\,\sqrt[3]{3}e^{i2\pi/3},\,\,\sqrt[3]{3}e^{-i2\pi/3} 
$$
this means that the most general $q_n$ is:
$$
q_n=\lambda_0 K_0^n+\lambda_1 K_1^n+\lambda_2 K_2^n=3^{n/3}\left(\lambda_0+\lambda_1 e^{i2n\pi/3}+\lambda_2 e^{-i2n\pi/3}\right)
$$
so putting it all together:
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n!}c_n=\frac{1}{n!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)q_n=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n!}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)3^{n/3}\left(\lambda_0+\lambda_1 e^{i2n\pi/3}+\lambda_2 e^{-i2n\pi/3}\right)$$
where the $\lambda$ are arbitrary complex numbers.